# I can not put the image below the text in TabPage headers

Tags: c#, winforms

Can you help me, I have a TabControl but I can not put the image below the text carries the headertab any ideas?

I use  c# and winform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign Images to TabPages, you can drop an ImageList on designer and add images to it, then select your `TabControl`, select `ImageList` property and set it to the image list you created. Then select `TabPages` property and edit tab pages, for each tab page, select an `ImageIndex` to show **image before text**.

But you should know **TabControl doesn't have built-in support for images below/above text automatically**, To do so, you should use Owner Drawn TabControl. You should set `DrawMode` property to `OwnerDrawFixed` and then handle [`DrawItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx) event and draw tab pages yourself.